# How to make my own LaTeX template?

Tags: code

Ok I know that my question is quite local, however, I have struggled with it for a long time and I could not find the answer, so I decided to post it here.

I have to rewrite a book (which was written using Word) by LaTeX, without changing the structure and the content.

This book is divided into 2 parts; part 1 has 2 chapters and part 2 has 3 chapters. Chapters are numbered by alphabet letter like `Chapter A`, `Chapter B`,... and theorems in each chapter are numbered depending in its chapter like `Theorem A1`, `Theorem B7`,...

I have searched on the Internet for book templates, but I found nothing that fully appropriate with this style of book. Every time I tried I got troubles with numbering theorem, with index and content.... :|

Could you please help me to write the appropriate LaTeX code? Please do not tell me that I should change the way the book behaves, since the author want to keep it, and I am just an editor only.

Thank for reading my question!

**update** : Here is the picture that I made :
[image]

For the theorem, I number it by hand, as the following code :

```
   \indent \textbf{Định lý A1.}
    (Thales thuận dạng hình học)\emph{Nếu ba đường thẳng đôi một song song $a, b, c$ cùng bị hai đường thẳng $\Delta, \Delta'$ tương ứng cắt tại $A, B, C; A’, B’, C’$ thì $\dfrac{AB}{BC}=\dfrac{A'B'}{B'C'}$. }
```

Comment: I think you should show a picture.

Comment: One thing to pay attention the next time: do not write `$a, b, c$`, write the longer `$a$, $b$, $c$` instead. Here you enumerate the three variables `a`, `b` and `c` and thus the comma needs to be outside the math environment to get the spacing correct.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very basic way, using the `book`-class and the `amsmath`-commands:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools} % loads the ams-packages and provides some fixes
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}} % change chapter numbering to A, B, C, ...
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem} % define new theorem style

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mytheorem} %first theorem - this will be "A.1"
\begin{align}
    a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{align}
\end{mytheorem}

\lipsum[2-5]

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[6-8]

\begin{mytheorem} %second theorem - this will be B.1
\begin{align}
    1+1=3
\end{align}
\end{mytheorem}

\lipsum[9]

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

### Edit

Based on your screenshot, try the following – you have to remove the old definition of `mytheorem` from the previous example, then add:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr} %allows you to reset counters within others

\newcounter{mytheoremcounter} %create a counter for your theorems
\setcounter{mytheoremcounter}{0}%set them to zero. At the begin of every theorem
    %, this gets increased by one, so the first theorem will be '1'
\counterwithin{mytheoremcounter}{chapter} % reset the counter in every chapter

\newenvironment{mytheorem}{%
    \addtocounter{mytheoremcounter}{1}%
    \indent\textbf{Theorem \thechapter\arabic{mytheoremcounter}.}
}{}
```

Then write the following:

```
\begin{mytheorem}
(Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet) \emph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Ut purus elit, vestibu- lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. $\Delta$, $\Delta'$ 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. $A, B, C; A’, B’, C’$ mollis ac, nulla
$\dfrac{AB}{BC}=\dfrac{A'B'}{B'C'}$. }  
\end{mytheorem}
```

This produces:

[image]

### Edit 2

The same result with an improved interface:

```
\newenvironment{mytheorem}[1]{
    \addtocounter{mytheoremcounter}{1}
    \indent\textbf{Theorem \thechapter\arabic{mytheoremcounter}.} (#1) \em
}{}
```

Use it like this:

```
\begin{mytheorem}{The title}
    The theorem
\end{mytheorem}
```

With the `\em` you do not need to write the `\emph{...}` every time.

Comment: Thank you ralfix for your answer, but I do not mean the theorem is labeled by (A1), but I mean it is Theorem A1 : $a^2+b^2=c^2$. So how can I numbering the theorem ?

Comment: If you replace the line `\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}` by `\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[chapter]`, the theorem heading will be of the form "Theorem A.1".

Comment: It surely is more "fitting" to use the `amsthm` package in such a case – but defining the environment himself it is possible to exactly match the given style without needing to define a new theorem style (if @NguyễnDuyKhánh wants the dot after the number, not as separator e.g.)

Comment: @ralfix: You can format the chapter heading as @NguyễnDuyKhánh requested by adding `\usepackage{titlesec}` and `\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bf\huge}{\Alph{chapter}.}{1pc}{}` in the preamble.

Comment: @ralfix you can add the following lines to your preamble to produce the desired sectional unit headers: `\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}{\thechapter.}{0.4em}{}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection.}{0.4em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{20pt}`